# All the records are not getting properly updated in multithreaded code

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a piece of code in which I need to call the rest web service for some records fetched from the result set and then update the same in the table.

I am setting up executor framework which executes the NewWorkerThread(Runnable instance) which in turn further contain an implementation of threadpool with fixed thread size of 30 and implements ThreadHelper (An instance of runnable interface) which try to call the web service in parallel and update the response in database when the batch size of 500 is reached. Now the problem that I am facing is that all the records fetched from the result set are not processed.Few of the records remain unprocessed. I am attaching the implementation of NewWorkerThread and ThreadHelper. I am also making use of GlobalAccessor class which contain the volatile fields which can be shared among multiple threads without any synchronization issue. Please suggest why all the records are not getting processed.

```
public NewWorkerThread(Connection conn, String query, Map map, String state) {

    this.conn = conn;
    // this.dist=dist;
    // this.seqNo=seqNo;
    this.query = query;

    // this.restTemplate=restTemplate;
    this.state = state;
    this.map = map;
    request = new GetNearestStopsRequest();
    // this.log=log;
    executorPool = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);

}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int count = 0;
    int totalCount = 0;
    /* PreparedStatement st1=null; */
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ResponseEntity<GetNearestStopsResponse> response = null;
    String transit_id = null;
    int start = 0;

    try {
        /* st1= conn.prepareStatement(Queries.updateRepoTable()); */
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        int mainCount = rs.getFetchSize();
        int counter = 0;

        System.out.println("fetch size is : " + mainCount);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (rs.next()) {
            counter++;
            for (start = 0; start < Constants.INTERNAL_THREAD_COUNT; start++) {
                // list = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
                String add1 = rs.getString("SRC_ADDRESS_LINE_1");
                String add2 = rs.getString("SRC_ADDRESS_LINE_2");
                String lat = rs.getString("SRC_LAT");
                String longitude = rs.getString("SRC_LONG");
                String city = rs.getString("SRC_PRAD_CITY");
                String state = rs.getString("SRC_PRAD_STATE");
                String zip = rs.getString("SRC_PRAD_ZIP");
                transit_id = rs.getString("TRANSIT_ID");
                String provSource = rs.getString("PROV_SOURCE");
                executorPool.execute(new ThreadHelper(add1, add2, lat, longitude, city, state, zip, transit_id,
                        provSource, map, this.conn, start));

            }
            System.out.println("GlobalAccessor.count[0] : " + GlobalAccessor.count[0]);
            start = 0;

            /*
             * for(Future<String> fut : list){ try {
             * System.out.println(fut.get()); st1.addBatch(fut.get());
             * //System.out.println(fut.get()); System.out.println(
             * "Added in batch"); } catch (InterruptedException |
             * ExecutionException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } }
             */

            for (start = 0; start < Constants.INTERNAL_THREAD_COUNT; start++) {
                if (counter % (Integer.parseInt((String) map.get("BATCHSIZE"))) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for tasks to end");
                    while (executorPool.getActiveCount() > 0) {

                    }

                    log.info("Count for " + start + " : " + GlobalAccessor.count[start]);
                    System.out.println("Going to execute !! ");
                    GlobalAccessor.recordCount = GlobalAccessor.recordCount + GlobalAccessor.count[start];
                    GlobalAccessor.count[start] = 0;
                    GlobalAccessor.globalSt.get(start).executeBatch();
                    GlobalAccessor.globalSt.get(start).clearBatch();
                    log.info("One batch completed for " + state);

                }
            }
            start = 0;

        }

        executorPool.shutdown();

        while (!executorPool.isTerminated()) {
        }
        System.out.println("going for final execute");
        for (start = 0; start < Constants.INTERNAL_THREAD_COUNT; start++) {
            GlobalAccessor.globalSt.get(start).executeBatch();
            GlobalAccessor.recordCount = GlobalAccessor.recordCount + GlobalAccessor.count[start];
            GlobalAccessor.count[start] = 0;
        }

        // conn.commit();
        log.info("Successfully executed for the state" + state + " in repo table");

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: You might want to look at `ExecutorCompletionService` to know the completed tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using a wrong pattern. Surely 
`while (executorPool.getActiveCount() > 0) { }` is definitively to be avoided.

Problem is about the execution of threads, whose end is not controlled in the right way.

If you want to run multiple parallel instances, you need to run them all then wait for their end using provided `java.util.concurrent` objects and methods: you don't have to implement thread wait, executors do it in your behalf. When last thread ends, processing can continue.

So pattern should be something like this:

```
public void worker()  {
   ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);
   ResultSet rs = findResultsetWithQuery(...)
   int idx = 0;
   while (rs.hasNext()) {
      List<Callable<...>> callables = new ArrayList<>();
      while (++idx % 30 > 0 && rs.hasNext()) {
          callables.add(new ThreadHelper(rs));
          }
      List<Future<...>> result = null;
      try {
          result = exec.invokeAll(callables, 180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      catch (Exception e) { ... blah .... }
      // here you can manage callables' results and exceptions
   }
}
```

In this way, the "invokeAll" invokes all callables in parallel, then waits until they all ends. Eventually, no more than 180 seconds. 
Avoid to use a huge number of executors, or overhead to manage internally fork/join risks to be really high. And absolutely, avoid that absurd `while(...) { }`

I hope this can help.